# Jquery get Value of an input in .on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

Im a beginner in Jquery / Javascript and have a problem getting a value in a variable after using .on (click). 
I know it doesnt work after i start.on, but I want to know, how i can get my value (i hope you can follow me)

My Jquery looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("click", "#main", function(event){
        var test = $("#firstName").value;
        alert(test);
    });
});
```

My html page is very simple, but here it is:

```
<input type="text" value="HEY THERE" placeholder="Text" name="box" id="firstName">
<a id="main" href="#">Submit Text</a>
```

The javascript alert comes up with "undefined", so i think my script cant find my HTML element.

I hope you understand my problem,
Greets :)

Comment: From where do you get the #firstName id you use in your selector?

Comment: id of your text input is "main" not "firstName" so use $("#main").val(); and make your ID unique..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
var test = $("#firstName").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

ID name should be unique, your code defined with the same ID name, you should replace

```
<input type="text" value="HEY THERE" placeholder="Text" name="box" id="main">
```

into this

```
<input type="text" value="HEY THERE" placeholder="Text" name="box" id="firstname">
```

and js should be

```
var test = $("#firstName").val();
```

Comment: Oh, the thing with the id's happened when i posted it here, so i always had #firstname as id on my text input :) So there are no changes, right ? This does not work in my case ...

Comment: Then you should edit posted, others might confuses :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have the same id (`main`) for two different controls. I guess you need to change the id of the input text to `firstName`.

Then, you can either use pure javascript:

```
var test = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
```

or jquery:

```
var test = $("#firstName").val();
```

Comment: @Clank  "#firstName" is an input field right? can you post your full updated code? did you also try `document.getElementById("firstName").value;`